# Disable overflow checks in VS Code's rust-analyzer tests but retain println

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I need to turn off overflow checks in unit tests. I can use command line to accomplish this using `cargo test --release`, however:

1. GUI test buttons provided by rust-analyzer provide a better experience, however they're configured to run on debug mode with overflow checks on.
2. `cargo test --release` hides `println!` statements, but I would like to see them.

Comment: You can also tell cargo to disable capturing with `cargo test --release -- --nocapture`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable overflow checking for tests in your Cargo.toml file:

```
[profile.test]
overflow-checks = false
```

Answer (score 1):

`cargo test -- --show-output` shows `println!()` statements